# How to listen to the data in a specific port?

Tags: python, server, rasa-core

I wiuld like to create a chatbot from [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/01/faq-chatbots-the-future-of-information-searching/), but it seems that the Rasa version is too old and suddenly the commands do not work.

I know how to recover and respond to messages through Slack, but I do not know how to do it from a web application that I develop with a chat interface.

With Slack, I launched the following script:

```
from rasa_core.channels import HttpInputChannel
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
#from rasa_slack_connector import SlackInput

nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/moodnlu')
agent = Agent.load('./models/dialogue',interpreter = nlu_interpreter)


# With Slack
# https://api.slack.com/apps/AASPDV196/oauth?
#input_channel = SlackInput('OAuth Access Token','Bot User OAuth Access Token', 'Verification Token',True)

#agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5004,'/',input_channel))

# With inner app
input_channel = SlackInput('OAuth Access Token','Bot User OAuth Access Token', 'Verification Token',True)
agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5000,'/',input_channel))
```

I know I have to modify `input_channel` so that he hears in the right port, but I really do not know how.

[Here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/rasa_core/channels/rest.py) is where HttpInputChannel comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the dialog model and nlu model ready, you can run Rasa core like this

```
$python -m rasa_core.server -d <DIALOGUE_MODEL_PATH> -u <NLU_MODEL_PATH> --debug -o out.log --cors *
```

and then in a different terminal, do below and you will get a response

```
$curl -XPOST localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond -d '{"query":"Hello"}'
```

If sender id matters to you, then below command if you want to pass `nad` as a sender id

```
$curl -XPOST localhost:5005/conversations/nad/respond -d '{"query":"Hello"}'
```

Works for NLU version `0.12.3` and Core version `0.9.0a6`

**UPDATE:**
If you are trying to build an UI around it

Run below in a terminal

```
$python -m rasa_core.server -d <DIALOGUE_MODEL_PATH> -u <NLU_MODEL_PATH> --debug -o out.log --cors *
```

In your server

```
import requests
import json

data = '{"query":"hello"}'
response = requests.post('http://localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond', data=data)
json_response = response.json()
print (json_response[0]['text'])
```

This should output the reply of `hello` in your terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works pretty well on the terminal. Do you know how to handle it when I send those requests from the user interface? Basically I did an [app.py](https://github.com/antoinecomp/myflaskapp/blob/master/app.py) that sends POST requests but for the moment I only got `HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /parse?q=Hello (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f117cf677f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))`

Comment: Ho It's okay it was just a port setting error. Still I have an exception when I send a message through the graphical interface: `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` whereas the Rasa server has the following answer: `2018-06-06 09:12:22+0100 [-] "127.0.0.1" - - [06/Jun/2018:08:12:21 +0000] "GET /parse?q=I+am+sad HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"`

Comment: @ChatBot show me the code you are using to send from the UI

Comment: Yes ! Perfect !!